# Bootstrap grid not working properly

Tags: gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the html structured like this

```
<div class=row>
<article class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
</article> </div>
```

But the col keeps stacking in 2 per page (border red) and the body is border blue. Can anyone suggest why?

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: have you tried i larger screen. If you are using chrome press `Ctrl` + `-`

Comment: I had body> article{ margin:5px} that was messing up the grid. I fixed it . Thanks for all responses